# I want to get weather update in android

Tags: android, weather

**What i have:** currently my app is telling me my current location (coordinates + name).

**What i want:** To get the weather update of my current location. and i want to update whenever my location is changed.

i have tried a tutorial but that was too much complex for me.

Comment: i have tried this link... http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WeatherListWidget/index.html

Comment: Here is sample weather widget used Yahoo API: http://code.google.com/p/yahooweatherandroid/

Comment: @nguyedar.... no buddy its useless !

Comment: Any one got solution for this. Any example or Working demo..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge you need a server support for the same.
I saw the tutorial, which parses the HTML page in "Beginning Android".
If you want that to be in specified format, then you need server support. Try searching for free server providers.

Comment: no Suman its not like that...this could be done without server.

Comment: Any one got solution for this. Any example or Working demo..?

Answer (score 1):

Use google weather API, you will get a XML response

Replace the city-name placeholder with the city detected
http://www.google.co.uk/ig/api?weather=

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample project with my own Yahoo weather api wrapper.
You can find it here.
https://github.com/zh-wang/YWeatherGetter4a

Answer (score 0):

Try Metwit [weather API](http://metwit.com/weather-api/).

It's simply to use, what do you need is only a lat, lng and a GET request.
If you can implement them client-side: 200 request/day (ip based throttling) no authentication required. Worldwide coverage, JSON and REST compliant.

[Here the documentation of the weather resource](http://metwit.com/weather-api/docs/resources/weather/).

Disclamer: I own this API.

Comment: Thanks alot for this response but this limitation of 200 requests is not good... for our app, there are more than 200 requests per day.. so we have used Yahoo Weather API's...

Comment: If you can implement client side you have 200 requests for IP, so the problem does not exists. ;)